# UCC3895 based power supply Confusion

Tags: power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, pwm, feedback, voltage-reference

I was working on the [UCC 3895](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ucc3895.pdf?ts=1692615494596&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FUCC3895%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Dapp-null-null-GPN_EN-cpc-pf-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DUCC3895%2526ds_k%253DUCC3895%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DEAIaIQobChMI6oeBiMztgAMVsdgWBR3B1AWEEAAYASAAEgIpPvD_BwE%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) IC in order to work on an SMPS design. I've seen the schematics of the IC and I could find any internal reference as done in some other PWM ICs like the UC3842 having that set to 2.5.

1. The datasheet gave a voltage of max of 3.6V for the EAP pin which is seen as a feedback pin. Its other pin is EAN, Do I have to set the 2.5/3.6V reference on my own in order to take the same application from it?
2. I have found a schematic where only EAP was used and the EAN was shorted to the output error, making a buffer-like behavior to the Error amplifier according to the diagram of the IC given below. In this circuit what is the reference set? Or it doesn't have any reference and do I have to disconnect the two EAN and EA out and set a voltage at the EAN/EAP pin and use others for feedback? The schematic is given  below:
   [image]

The complete block diagram of the UCC3895:
[image]

For the reference voltage:
[image]

In one of the sample diagrams they also showed the EAN and EAOUT to be shorted, and therefore I cant find any circuit which sets 3.6V outside or an internal circuit in the IC where the feedback is compared with the 3.6V:
[image]

Comment: Q1 - You cannot exceed 3.6V at the EAP input. And this limitation also applies to EAN input as well.   Q2 - They are using TL431 as an error amplifier. Thus, all the gain will be provided by TL431 itself. No additional open loop gain is needed. And that is why the UCC3895 internal error amplifier is connected as a voltage follower (gain = 1V).  Because a circuit with too much gain + negative feedback is not a good idea. The circuit will be prone to oscillations and it will be hard to make it work stable.

Comment: @G36 is correct, the TL431 acts as a reference and error amplifier at the same time.  Since this part is typically used with isolated topologies, that would be the most common approach.

Comment: @G36 is the 3.6V set internally? because I cant fount any input to the error amplifier where it is compared with 3.6V.

Comment: @kam1212 The 3.6 V spec is the max recommended common-mode input voltage for the error amp.  It's not a voltage that's developed internally or compared to anything.  The TL431 provides the reference voltage in the example schematic.

Comment: @JohnD the schematic shows that tl431 provides the feedback only, it doesn't seem to set the reference.

Comment: @kam1212 It does set the reference.  See here: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/TND381-D.PDF

Comment: Internal reference: pin 4 "REF". This device has more pins and more general functionality, so instead of tying the error amp to internal ref, they provide both inputs for free use. Normally you would just tie one side to REF or a divider. Or use a secondary side TL431.

Comment: Isn't the TL431 just simply a kind of witch that allows the current to flow through it when it gets more than 2.5 V on the reference pin of TL431?  Here this reference on the TL431 is just for sensing and giving input to the IC in the form of feedback. Here in the final schematic, they have done that but they do not have that constant fixed voltage for comparison. From where are they getting that?

Comment: @TimWilliams kindly help me in this. A little clarification is need.

Comment: Yes, TL431 will conduct more or less current depending on the voltage at the reference pin. But you forget that TL431 has a "large gain". Small changes around 2.5V at the reference pin, will cause huge changes in the "cathode" current and we also have negative feedback loop.  And this is enough to achieve stable output voltage determined by feedback resistors ratio and TL431 Vref voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the UCC3895 doesn't have an internal reference voltage set. The UCC3895 uses the TL431 for the generation of the reference as it has an internal comparator that tries to maintain the voltage at the reference equal to approximately 2.5V when the cathode and the reference are connected directly or indirectly. Thus in this way, the IC gets an external reference instead of having a specific internal reference.
Secondly, yes if you want to give another voltage reference you can use the EAN pin for that purpose.